# Monacaのデバッグビルドが終わらない

Tags: monaca, build

Monacaで作ったアプリをデバッグビルドしようとしているのですが、iOSの場合は「ビルド準備中」の表示のまま、Androidの場合は「ビルド中」の表示のまま、どれだけ待ってもビルドが完了しません。
失敗で終了してくれればまだ原因の究明方法があるのですが・・・。
ちなみに同じアプリで以前もデバッグビルドを行ったことがあり、iOS向けの証明書などはすでに登録済です。
このような状態になる原因はなんでしょうか？
アドバイスいただけますよう、お願いします。

Comment: Monacaの方に直接問い合わせした方がよろしいかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

ビルドサーバ障害だったようです。
Monacaの動作がおかしいと思ったら、まず最初に障害情報をチェックするようにしてください。
https://ja.monaca.io/headline/fault.html

Answer (score -1):

デフォルトインデックスページ（プロジェクト作成時の初期ファイル）は削除していないでしょうか？
自分で、index.htmlを作ると、デバッガーでは空きません。
そのため、もし、削除していれば、プロジェクトをエクスポートして、ダウンロードフォルダを開き、コピーして、保存。そして、新規プロジェクトを作り直して、デフォルトページを残す必要があります。そのインデックスには、書き足してかまいません。